# How to associate a SQL table with elasticsearch index?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I am a student and i started working on a spring boot multi-module project where i need to use a Oracle database for some tables and elasticsearch for another table but i can't figure out how to relate between the two yet ,i thought i'd create a module that uses Jpa repos and a module that uses a elasticsearch repo but i don't know how to join the two .
So am wondering if anybody have an idea, an example or documentation that could help . thank you.

Comment: You have to create a relationship between the Oracle DB table and a document on Elasticsearch? If so, then it is as simple as putting the Oracle DB table's primary key in the document on Elasticsearch and/or vice-versa.

Comment: and it does not bother if  they are in different modules right ?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't matter. If you have to query Elasticsearch by using Oracle DB table's primary key, then having this primary key replicated in the Elasticsearch document is enough - I said primary key, but it can be any column that can be used to represent a relationship, actually... Just be sure that the field you replicate doesn't change overtime.

Comment: i see , Okay well thank you so much @MatheusCirillo